# subquery in parse whereKey:doesNotMatchKey:inQuery: where innerquery returns objects, not strings

Tags: ios, parse-platform, subquery

I'm trying to get the objects (MainObject) that are not contained in an inner query but it doesn't work.
It returns objects as if no innerquery were defined.

I suppose it is becouse my innerquery returns objects and in whereKey:doesNotMatchKey:inQuery: it is waiting a String to compare with objectId.

```
PFQuery *queryInner = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"InnerObject"];
[queryInner whereKey:@"status" equalTo:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]];
[queryInner selectKeys:@[@"principalObject"]];

PFQuery *queryPrincipal = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"MainObject"];
[queryPrincipal whereKey:@"owner" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
[queryPrincipal whereKey:@"objectId" doesNotMatchKey:@"principalObject" inQuery:queryInner];

[queryPrincipal findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *returnedData, NSError *error) {
...
...
```

Is it possible to extract the objectIDs of the objects in the innerQuery with out 2 requests?
Is it possible to compare a column (objectId), which is a String, with an Object in another column (principalObject)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Wes in Parse Google Groups has suggested: https://groups.google.com/d/msgid/parse-developers/46b5b8a9-dbb8-464d-8f54-db884e95d49e%40googlegroups.com

My solution to this problem has been to add an extra key to my "InnerObject" table that contains just the objectId. So you would have the pointer column (principalObject) and the ID (principalObjectId). With the ID as a string the query works but we have a new unnecessary column in the InnerObject wasting some space and overloading a little the creation of objects

To make this easy, just add it into the beforeSave of "InnerObject" in cloud code. For example...

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("InnerObject", function(request, response) {
  var myInnerObject = request.object;
  if (myInnerObject.get("principalObject") != null && myInnerObject.get("principalObject").id != myInnerObject.get("principalObjectId")) { //Make sure it is set and it is not done 
    myInnerObject.set("pricipalObjectId", myInnerObject.get("principalObject").id); //The pointer won't have other data but it does have the ID
  }
  response.success();
});
```

It would be REALLY nice if there was just a query constraint whereDoesNotMatchQuery: which admits pointer to objects not just string keys.